# Twitter typeaheads autocomplete fails with dots (.), dashes (-) and ampersands (&) in

Tags: javascript, twitter, typeahead, bloodhound

We're using the twitter typeaheads and it auto completes the value, until you type a dot, slash or &.  Then the auto complete does not show any values.

So if I type South, it will show South&Dakota and South&Carolina, but when I type the '&' it does not show any values.

According to [this link on github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/407) the tokenizers might be the solution, but I can't find a workable solution.  Any ideas or assistance?

```
var states = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.nonword('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: states
});

states.initialize();
$('#txtState').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
}
```

Comment: Maybe write your own tokenizer if you don't like the way the default one works?